# passing parameter onClick, React

Tags: reactjs, redux, undefined

i have this slice of code:

```
const ChangeRequest = ({
  inRelease,
  title,
  requestId,
  cost,
  supervisor,
  chipText,
  description,
  showModal,
}) => (
  <div
    onClick={() => showModal({
      modal: 'changeRequestDetail',
      state: { title },
    })}
    className={styles.crContainer}
  >
```

***Main problem***

in the const ChangeRequest i've the value `title`, i need to pass this value to the onClick property of the modal.

***modal***

```
<div
    onClick={() => showModal({
      modal: 'changeRequestDetail',
      state: { title },
    })}
    className={styles.crContainer}
  >
```

In this way if i try to `console.log(title)` i get `undefined` as value.

***Question***

how can i pass the value of title to the value `state` of show modal in the onClick function ?

***Added the showModal***

so i called it with mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  showModal: showModalAction,
};
```

this is the relative action

```
export const SHOW_MODAL = 'SHOW_MODAL';
export const HIDE_MODAL = 'HIDE_MODAL';

export function showModalAction(params) {
  return dispatch => dispatch({
    type: SHOW_MODAL,
    payload: params,
  });
}

export function hideModalAction(params) {
  return dispatch => dispatch({ type: HIDE_MODAL });
}
```

this is his reducer:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import { SHOW_MODAL, HIDE_MODAL } from '../actions/modalActions';

const initialState = Map({
  type: null,
  state: null,
});

const modalReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      return state
        .set('type', action.payload.modal)
        .set('state', action.payload.state);

    case HIDE_MODAL:
      return state
        .set('type', null)
        .set('state', null);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default modalReducer;
```

Comment: Ok so I assume in your `ChangeRequest` and `onClick` functions, if you print `title` at those steps, it's actually got a value. If not, then sort that out first. But if it is defined, can you add your `showModal` function and how it's trying to access that title value.

Comment: yes, the title has actually a value, i'm sure of this because if i try to 
{console.log(title) outside the div with the onClick, i got the exact value of title. I'm posting it!

Comment: @Legeo ok so first why is your action returning a function, rather than just an object. It looks like you've made the `SHOW_MODAL` action as if it's an async `redux-thunk` type action, but it doesn't seem to be, just seems like a regular, synchronous action to me. Secondly, where it the the value being lost, when you check for `action.payload.state` in the reducer's `SHOW_MODAL` case?

Comment: Can you pass it like this : state: title , instead of this state: { title }, Will that work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, after several tries i succeed to got the Data. 
What was the problem ?

we need to `mapStateToProps` the data from the state of the modal. Why ? because the modal was a reducer.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import styles from './styles.module.css';
import BlueLightRow from './BlueLightRow';
import DetailSection from './DetailSection';
import Modal from '../../../components/Modal';
import Header from './Header';

function ChangeDetail({
  title, supervisor, architect, initiator, id, cost, description, chipText,
}) {
  return (
    <Modal noPadding bigDialog>
      {console.log(title)}
      <div className={styles.blueBackground}>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Header title={title} chipText={chipText} />
          <BlueLightRow cost={cost} id={id} />
          <DetailSection supervisor={supervisor} architect={architect} claimant={initiator} description={description} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}

ChangeDetail.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  architect: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  initiator: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  supervisor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  cost: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  chipText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  title: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'title']),
  architect: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'architect']),
  initiator: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'initiator']),
  supervisor: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'supervisor']),
  description: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'description']),
  cost: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'cost']),
  id: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'requestId']),
  chipText: state.getIn(['modalReducer', 'state', 'chipText']),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ChangeDetail);
```

If someone will need more explanation about the code i will be happy to go deep if i can :)